# Bartik theme: How to extend text/content below blocks in sidebar 1 and 2

Tags: theming

Am using the Bartik theme on my site. I noticed that whenever i place a block in the sidebar 1 and sidebar 2, all the space below the block becomes 'redundant' (i.e. content is limited to the middle of the page.) All the text on the page becomes restricted to the middle of the page.

Please, is there a way to make the content/text extend below the blocks in side bar 1 or 2?

Answer (score 0):

Edit your page.tpl.php
Cut and paste both the sidebar sections into the content section.
Content section starts with:     `<div id="content" class="column"><div class="section">`

I mean these parts:

```
<?php if ($page['sidebar_first']): ?>
    <div id="sidebar-first" class="column sidebar"><div class="section">
      <?php print render($page['sidebar_first']); ?>
    </div></div> <!-- /.section, /#sidebar-first -->
  <?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($page['sidebar_second']): ?>
  <div id="sidebar-second" class="column sidebar"><div class="section">
    <?php print render($page['sidebar_second']); ?>
  </div></div> <!-- /.section, /#sidebar-second -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

I think you will need some extra CSS to make it look nice.